# Meaning of "Betriebsstrom" in an ISTA bill

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Betriebsstrom" in the context of an ISTA bill?

A detailed explanation of the bill would also be appreciated :-).

[image: scanned bill]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the kind of heating system we are talking about here, I'd interpret it like this:

**Betriebsstrom** refers to electric power required to make a system work. In case of a heating system, this may include power that is used for pumps, compressors and for monitoring systems (but *not* as the main source of energy).

Detailed explanation of the bill (we usually don't do such translation services stuff here, but I'm kind of bored at the moment):

- 6000 EUR have been used for fuel
- 3000 EUR have been used for electric power required to make the system work
- plus a fee of 145.77 EUR for recording/measuring the "Verbrauch" (I'm not absolutely sure if this refers to the systems consumption of fuel/electricity or the customers consumption of heat)

Which amounts to a total cost of 9145.77 EUR for the building.

The second part is about how much of this *you* have to pay.

It seems that 30% of the costs are distributed based on the size of the apartments.
As the total size of the building is 261 square meters and 2743.73 EUR are distributed that way, you've got to pay roughly 10.5 EUR per square meter - in your case, as your apartment is 98 square meters, 1030.21 EUR.

The other 70% of the total are distributed based on consumption, 33382.04 kWh have been used in total, of which you used 9707 kWh, which is why you've got to pay another 1861.57 EUR.

So in total (as you've probably already guessed) you have to pay 2891.78 EUR.

Comment: There is a court decision, that the "Betriebsstrom" is not allowed to exceed 5% of the fuel costs. Betriebskosten are often estimated values. It could be that they are estimated too high in your case.

Comment: @Axel it could be that part of the system in use here is a heat pump (**Wärmepumpe**). In that case, it would not be unusual for a significant portion of the required power to be in form of electricity. I don't know enough about the legal situation to tell whether it is correct to use the term **Betriebskosten** for that, though.

Comment: That's a good point! Didn't think of heat pumps.